# Check if an object has a user defined prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

Simply put can I check if an object has a user defined prototype?

Example;

```
var A = function() {};

var B = function() {};

B.prototype = {

};

// Pseudocode
A.hasUserPrototype(); // False
B.hasUserPrototype(); // True
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you call user defined? A prototype that was not created by you?

Comment: You're only setting prototype as a property of those objects, there's no prototypal inheritance that will occur with the example you've provided.

Comment: @zzzzBov I know this. But still in my example I have modified the prototype by assigning it an empty object, is there a way to check this?

Comment: @GriffLab, you have not modified "the prototype" you have only modified an attribute on the object that happens to be called "prototype".

Comment: @GriffLab: "Prototype" is a very specific term in JavaScript. In your example, you have **not** changed the prototype of the object, you just have created a totally arbitrary property with the name `prototype`. Only the `prototype` property of **functions** is treated in a special way. If you just want to test whether a property exists or not, you should phrase the question differently (and I'm sure it's a duplicate then).

Comment: I will re write my question in my code I do have functions, I just wrote this without thinking, thanks.

Comment: @GriffLab, when you declare a function, they're automatically instantiated with a new object as their `prototype` property. You don't need to re-declare prototype as an object, although it can be convenient for setting a bunch of methods all at once.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you want to find out whether an object is an instance of a custom constructor function, you can just compare its prototype against `Object.prototype`:

```
function hasUserPrototype(obj) {
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) !== Object.prototype;
}
```

Or if you maintain the `constructor` property properly:

```
function hasUserPrototype(obj) {
    return obj.constructor !== Object;
}
```

This would also work in browsers which don't support `Object.getPrototypeOf`.

But both solutions would return `true` also for other native objects, like functions, regular expressions or dates. To get a "better" solution, you could compare the prototype or constructor against all native prototypes/constructors.

---

**Update:**

If you want to test whether a **function** has a user defined `prototype` value, then I'm afraid there is no way to detect this. The initial value is just a simple object with a special property (`constructor`). You *could* test whether this property exists (`A.prototype.hasOwnProperty('constructor')`), but if the person who set the prototype did it right, they properly added the `constructor` property after changing the prototype.

Comment: @dandavis: Because `"fred"` is a primitive value, not an object.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Felix King accurately addressed the issue of inheritance, so I will address the concept of existing properties instead</sub>

If you're simply trying to check for the presence of a property named `prototype` on an object, you can use:

```
a.hasOwnProperty('prototype')
```

This will return true for:

```
a = {
    //the object has this property, even though
    //it will return undefined as a value
    prototype: undefined 
};
```

This assumes that the object is not being treated as a hashmap, where other properties, such as `hasOwnProperty` have been set, otherwise, a safer way of checking for the presence of a property is:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a, 'prototype')
```

This can be turned into a generic function as:

```
has = (function (h) {
    "use strict";
    return function (obj, prop) {
        h.call(obj, prop);
    };
}(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty));
```

and used as:

```
has(a, 'prototype');
```

Answer (score 0):

For A object prototype will be undefined:

```
typeof A.prototype == "undefined" // true
typeof B.prototype == "undefined" // false
```

Comment: I'm afraid of `undefined` being defined.

Comment: @Riateche I agree with you on this.

Comment: really? i'm all for defensive coding, but i've never see anyone redefine undefined to something else...

Comment: `A.prototype = undefined` will set a property called `prototype` on the object, and will return an incorrect value with this code.

Comment: @dandavis: That's not necessarily true. I made some tests recently and it turned out that both ways are equally fast, at least in Chrome. `typeof` is not a function but an operator and hence probably quite fast.

Comment: Notice that this does not work for functions, which have a `prototype` by default…

Comment: @Bergi, actually, it *does* work for functions, because the object has its own prototype property. Conceptually it's identical to a user-defined prototype property.