# Checking whether toString has been assigned

Tags: javascript

I want a debugging output function to contain a test: if the object has a toString function, use it.

But then, every JavaScript object has a toString function, so what I really want is to check whether it has been assigned toString instead of just inheriting a default one.

What's the best way to do this? It occurs to me maybe you could exploit the fact that the inherited function isn't visible in for-in iteration, though it feels like there ought to be an O(1) solution.

Comment: Give it a name that isn't a default function? Or assign a property to check to the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like
`obj.hasOwnProperty('toString')`

Answer (score 2):

The result of `obj.hasOwnProperty('toString')` depends on the way how your `toString` implementation is created. I did some simple test:

```
function A() {
}

A.prototype.toString = function(){
   console.log("A.toString");
};

function B() {
   this.toString = function(){
      console.log("B.toString");
   }
}

var t = [new A(), new B(), new A()];

for(var i=0; i<t.length; i++) {
    var hasOwnToString = t[i].hasOwnProperty("toString");
    console.log(hasOwnToString);

    if(hasOwnToString) {
       t[i].toString();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
false
true
B.toString
false
```

For A style it's `false`, but for B style it's `true`

Comment: the code is correct.. A does not have `toString` its prototype object has..

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if the toString function is the same as `Object` (the object all objects descend from)

```
function hasUserPrototype(obj) {
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).toString !== Object.prototype.toString;
}
```

See [Check if an object has a user defined prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597170/check-if-an-object-has-a-user-defined-prototype)

```js
function Foo() 
{
}

// toString override added to prototype of Foo class
Foo.prototype.toString = function()
{
    return "[object Foo]";
}

var f = new Foo();

function Boo() 
{
}

var g = new Boo();

function hasUserPrototype(obj) {
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).toString !== Object.prototype.toString;
}

document.write(hasUserPrototype(f)); // true
document.write(hasUserPrototype(g)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = {}
if (!(x.hasOwnProperty("toString"))) {
  x.toString = function() {
    return "I am X"
  }
}
x.toString()
// "I am X"
```